# How is isalnum() getting his return value in C?

Tags: c

For a school assignement i have to reproduce the behaviour of the *isalnum()* function in C. My issue is in getting the same int returned. How is *isalnum()* determining the value of the positive int it can return ?

Comment: Is it OK if the behavior matches the specification, or you have to reproduce the behavior of `isalnum()` in a specific environment?

Comment: It doesn't matter what exact positive number it returns, and it depends on the compiler. You can always return 1 or 0, that should be enough for the assignment.

Comment: I tried to call isalnum() on a simple char test1 = 'a' and it returned 8. the same value was returned with a call on char test2 = '2'

Comment: `int your_function(int x) { return isalnum(x); }` OK, solved!

Comment: i think it's ok if it matches the specification, but I also want to understand why i get those values. @HolyBlackCat answered that for me so thanks y'all

Comment: Yes, but the spec only says it has to return a positive number or not, so no portable program should care _what_ that number is, other than positive or not. So again, why does it matter? If the school assignment really asks to reproduce some implementation detail, that is dismal

Comment: Different compilers can return different values when the character is in the required set, because `isalnum()` is required to return a **non-0 value**.

Comment: Source codes of some standard libraries are made public. What is your environment?

Comment: Visual studio code on Ubuntu 20.04 @MikeCAT

Comment: Then you are probably using libc. The definition of `isalnum` is in [`ctype.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=ctype/ctype.h;h=351495aa4feaf23993fe65afc0760615268d044e;hb=HEAD).

Comment: It is pointless replicating a *specific* non-0 value, because *nobody checks that*, knowing that "a non-0 value" is the spec, and compilers can return any non-0 value.

Comment: The ctype.h functions are often implemented using a lookup table with 256 entries. The character is used as the index into that table. The entries in the table contain bit patterns that represent the type of the character. So `isalum(int c)` could be implemented as `return ctype_table[c] & 8;` where 8 is a bit that's set for all alpha and numeric characters.

Comment: "How is isalnum() determining the value of the positive int it can return ?" --> It is implementation defined. " to reproduce the **behaviour** of the isalnum() function", your code only needs to return non-zero when `isalpha(c) || isdigit(c)` is true and 0 otherwise. To mimic the behavior the same non-zero value is **not** needed. The coding goal of "getting the same int" is generally  _not_ possible per spec , but practical with @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica.

Answer (score 1):

Build it from other functions in `ctype.h`:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int my_isalnum(int c)
  {
  return isalpha(c) | isdigit(c);
  }
```